# How to make number of equally sized bins as input for histogram in tableau

Tags: histogram, tableau-api, bins, input-parameters

[image: Link for Screenshot of tableau]I have created a histogram

I am able to give bin size as input parameter

But i want user to input number of bins (x).
Result should have x number of equally sized bins

Please help me with this

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you show us how you got to the point you're at now? That way, we can help you get where you want to be.

Comment: His Simon, Thanks for responding, I have data regarding scale score which is a measure, i have plotted a histogram for the same. But i am not able to make the number of bins as user input.

Comment: I have also added the screenshot of histogram created

Comment: I don't you can get equally sized bins as scalesource measure will always vary